# Rails: Store has many Images; best practice to define "main image"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model

My models include Stores which have a number of Images. (There are other models that can have Images, too.)
Out of all Images that are assigned to a Store, I would like to set a "main image" which will be presented first on the Store's page. Other than that the main image should be treated in the same way as all others.

What is the best practice?

The models basically look like this:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding a foreign key reference to the stores table is not actually a bad idea.

Since polymorphic relationships are resolved in the software layer and not in the RBDMS there is nothing in the DB which maintains the referential integrity. The DB will for example happily let you delete the primary image for a store.

First lets generate a migration:

```
class AddPrimaryImageToStores < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    # we need to setup the foreign_key manually
    add_reference :stores, :primary_image, foreign_key: false
    add_foreign_key :stores, :images, column: 'primary_image_id'
  end
end
```

Then lets setup the relation:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images, as: :imageable, dependent: :destroy

  belongs_to :primary_image, class_name: 'Image'
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

  # one to one.
  has_one :primary_store, class_name: 'Store'
                          foreign_key: 'primary_image_id'

end
```

The direct relationship with a foreign key allows you to perform highly effective joins which is especially important if you are displaying stores and the primary image together.

Comment: Thanks for being so specific! This is helpful. But I am not sure if one-to-one is necessary to be made explicit. An Image can only belong to one :imageable, so :primary_store would always have to be the same as :imageable (unless I am misunderstanding something). EDIT: Oh wait - the fact that one Store can have many Images but any Image only one store needs to be made explicit, because it isn't yet, right? So I should do that for the :imageable?

Comment: The relationship you have is between store and imageable is fine if you want to have a one to many relationship. Thats not what I am getting at. If you want to do something like list all the stores and display them with the primary image you will want a non-polymorphic relationship which can be joined effectively.

Comment: max, how to prevent destroying the image of its a primary image at store? And, if have another store like table that's have a primary image too, I will have to add a new has_one, right?

Answer (score 0):

You can add some boolean field to your image model to define if image is main, and add scope to your model to get this main image by that new boolean field

Comment: I thought about maybe instead adding a foreign reference to the Store model which contains an Image id. I would have to validate that "main_image_id" refers to an Image whose "imageable" is precisely that store. But I want to stick to whatever is considered best practice in this scenario.